# Changing value of ruby variables/references

Tags: ruby, variables, reference, scope

I just stumbled upon something i don't quite understand. I know that variables in ruby are references. So that awesome stuff is possible. But when i pass a variable to a method, it behaves strangely:

```
my_var_a = "nothing happend to me"
my_var_b = "nothing happend to me"

def parse_set(my_var_set)
  my_var_set = "my value changed"
end

def parse_sub(my_var_sub)
  my_var_sub.sub! /(.*)/, "my value changed"
end

parse_set(my_var_a)
parse_sub(my_var_b)

my_var_a # => "nothing happend to me"
my_var_b # => "my value changed"
```

Can you explain to me why it works with `sub!` and `=` leaves the object unchanged? How can I avoid to use `sub!` but having the same result?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`my_var_a` and `my_var_set` are different references, but they point at the same object.  If you modify the object in `my_var_set`, the change shows up in `my_var_a`.  However, if you repoint `my_var_set` at a new object, that doesn't change what `my_var_a` points at.

**Edit:** clarification...

What Ruby does is called passing references by value. When you say

```
my_var_a = "nothing happend to me"
```

Ruby saves the string "nothing happend to me" in a memory location (let's call it 1000), and saves the `my_var_a` reference in another memory location (let's say 2000).  When your code uses `my_var_a`, the interpreter looks at location 2000, see that it points to 1000, then gets the actual string value from 1000.

When you call `parse_set(my_var_a)`, Ruby actually creates a new reference named `my_var_set` and points it to the string that `my_var_a` was pointing at (memory location 1000).  However, `my_var_set` is a copy of the `my_var_a` reference -- let's say `my_var_set` was created at memory location 3000.  `my_var_a` and `my_var_set` are 2 completely different references in memory, they just happen to point at the same exact memory location which holds the string value.

The statement `my_var_set = "my value changed"` in `parse_set` creates a new string in memory and points `my_var_set` at that new memory location.  However, this doesn't change what the original `my_var_a` reference points at!  Now that `my_var_set` points at a different memory location, nothing that you do to that variable will affect `my_var_a`.

The same reference copy happens for `parse_sub` as well.  But the reason that `parse_sub` changes the string is because you're calling a method directly on the `my_var_sub` reference.  When you do this, the interpreter gets the object that `my_var_sub` is pointing at and then modifies it.  So that change will show up in the `my_var_a` reference, because it still points at the same string.

Comment: Can you somehow rephrase that? I don't really get the part about repointing :) (also i changed the variable names for less ambiguity) And how can i change the value without using a ridiculous sub! and regex?

Comment: I added a little more information, hope that makes things clearer.  Passing reference by value is complicated, and takes a while to realize what's going on.

Also, to change the value without using sub, just have your `parse` method return a value, and assign it to the original variable: `my_var_a = some_parse_method(my_var_a)`.

Comment: Wow, that is a really good and simple explanation. Thank you!

Comment: "Pass reference by value" is the most accurate way to describe how Ruby works.

Answer (score 6):

```
irb(main):008:0* a = 'abc'
=> "abc"
irb(main):009:0> a.replace('def')
=> "def"
irb(main):010:0> a
=> "def"
```

I've had to use `replace` exactly zero times in all the years I've been programming in Ruby.  I wonder if there's a better design for your code.

Most string methods which change the receiver are suffixed by ! (sub!, capitalize!, chomp!, etc.)  Some that change the receiver are not suffixed by ! (replace is one).  If you call a method that changes the receiver, any and all references to that object will see the change.  if you call a method that does not change receiver, the method returns a *new string*.

gsub does not modify the receiver, but instead returns a new instance of String:

```
a = "foo"
b = a
p a.sub(/o/, '#')     # "f##"
p a                   # => "foo"
p b                   # => "foo"
```

gsub! does modify the receiver:

```
a = "foo"
b = a
p a.sub!(/o/, '#')    # => "f#o"
p a                   # => "f#o"
p b                   # => "f#o"
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the replace method. But the answer of Kaleb   explained to me the internals so I could understand what's going on, otherwise I would've accepted your answer :D

Answer (score 0):

"How can I avoid to use sub! but having the same result?"

```
def parse_set()
  "my value changed"
end

a = parse_set()
```

Set it as an instance variable of an object (although this works just in your main script, I recommend making your own class if you want to use the instance variables approach).

```
@my_var_a = "nothing happend to me"

def parse_set()
  @my_var_a = "my value changed"
end
```